# echo all URLs matching regex

Tags: bash, webserver, https

For a project I'm working on I need to get a list of all URLs in a certain folder of a domain, or better yet all URLs matching a regular expression.

I want to do this using bash so as to avoid installing any programs that I won't ever end up using, but if there is a solution using programs I might already have, such as FireFox, please go ahead and tell me.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: You can use [grep regex](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux)  and [find command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) . Something like this : " find . | grep -E "blah blah blah"

Comment: I don't understand how this would work as I don't believe find accepts URLs.

Comment: You mentioned in the post that you want to "get a list of all URLs in a certain folder of a domain" . In order to list the contents of a folder , you can use find.But if you want to get the list via a file or so , you can use grep directly . See the tutorial.

Comment: But I don't have a file containing the URLs, I only folder in a domain (maybe I'm using incorrect terminology), specifically https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/

Comment: Are you the owner of the server and have access to the directories or you want to get the URLs via web API ? In the first case , you can easily use "find" and in the second case , you can download the webpage via " curl " or "wget " and try GREPping there. For instance you can use  ' grep "href" ' to find the links.

Comment: The folder is open to anyone, you can see thi by simply following the link. I could download the entire folder and but that would use a bunch of drive space that I'd rather not use not to mention network bandwidth to download the contents of the files when all I want is the directory structure.

Comment: I think you want something like this " curl https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/ | grep -E "\<a href\>" | grep -E "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]" " . Copy and paste it to see whether it's something like what you want.

Comment: I couldn't get you command working in a useful way, but i did figure ou a command that dose output all the URLs, I just need to parse it now. The command is `wget -o ./urls.txt --spider -r --reject="index.html" --no-verbose --no-parent https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to manage this in my case, much should be the same for anyone else, you should be able to adapt this process to work for with any URL.

1. **Change to a new directory**
   First we should change to a new directory to avoid files getting lost or being kept after we need them.
   `mkdir ~/Desktop/dev`
   `cd ~/Desktop/dev`
2. **Get URLs with `wget`**
   Next we use the `wget` command to find all URLs for files and folders in the domain, for me the command was :
   `wget -o ./urls.txt --spider -r --reject="index.html" --no-verbose --no-parent https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/`
   Just replace the URL in the above command and it sould create a text file (`urls.txt`) full of URLs and a bunch of other nonsense.
3. **Remove folder left by`wget`**
   `wget` will have left behind a folder named what ever the domain of your input URL is. There is no important information in this folder, so go ahead and remove it with the `rm` command or through your file manager.
4. **Build a regex to extract the actual URLs**
   This is the hard part, I recommend opening `urls.txt` in a text edit or that allows finding with regexs and open [regexer](https://regexr.com/) in your browser, now you have to build a . Once you find a regex that matches the URLs run the command :
   `grep -o -E "(https.*\/([0-9](\.[0-9])+)\/(mono\/)?Godot_v\2[-_]stable[_-](mono_)?((win)?(x11[\._])?(osx\.?)?)((32)?(64)?)?((\.exe)?(\.fat)?)\.zip)" ./urls.txt >> urls\ filtered.txt`
   This will copy all lines matching the regex to a text file (`urls filtered.txt`) .Replace the regex (the bit in the quotes) with you regex.

After all that you should be left with a text file of all the URLs that you need.